# Dealing with WHERE IN(?) in Android SQLite raw query

Tags: android, sqlite

How to deal with raw queries in Android DB that contain a lot of arguments? For example `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column IN (15, 14, 17, 19)`. Can I use precompiled SQL with `?` selections, or is there no other choice than to format each query individually with concatenation?

I'm doing

```
SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery("... WHERE table.column IN (?)", selectionArgs);
```

where `selectionArgs` is `String` of joined IDs, but the query won't execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You have to use `... WHERE table.column IN (?, ?, ?, ?)` and add the parameters separately.